# ngx-bootstrap typeahead does't work

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, ngx-bootstrap, rxjs6

i have the following code to use ngx-bootstrap typeahed.

My html template:

```
<input [typeahead]="dataSource"
       typeaheadWaitMs="1000"
       (valueChanged)="selectMember($event)"
       [formControl]="form.controls['membernumber']" class="form-control" id="member">
```

And this is my typescript code:

```
 this.dataSource = Observable.create((observer: any) => {
   // Runs on every search
   observer.next(this.form.controls['membernumber'].value);
 })
  .pipe(
    mergeMap((token: string) => this.memberService.getMembersBySearchQuery2(token))
  );
```

The service implementation for getMemberBySearchQuery2 is this:

```
public getMembersBySearchQuery2(query: string) : Observable<Member[]>{
let params = new HttpParams().set('query', query);
let options = this.authenticationService.getAuthenticationOptions();
return this.http.get<Member[]>(this.urlService.getMemberServiceUrl(), {
   headers: options,
   params: params
  });
}
```

In the network traffi i can see that the request is sening to the backend and i get a response. The response is a array of members.

But nothing is showing in the browser. Nothing happens.

I use Angular6 and ngx-bootsrap 2.0.0

Comment: You should try 3.0.1, the 2.0.x version uses rxjs 5

Comment: Sorry my mistake i uise "ngx-bootstrap": "^3.0.1", and "rxjs": "^6.2.2"

Comment: can you please show imports of your module

Comment: These are the imports:


import {Observable} from "rxjs/index";

import {mergeMap} from "rxjs/internal/operators";

Comment: I solve the issue!

The flag typeaheadAsync="true" was missing in the html template file.

This information is complete missing in die documentation!

Now it work's